# php get array element by position instead of numeric key

Tags: php, arrays, position, key

I have a script that sorts input taking into account parent-child relations and the given display-order of each. A simplified array could look like this (the actual array has sub-arrays for children as well)

```
$output = Array
(
    [7] => first array
    [3] => second array
    [1] => last array
)
```

In which the keys are the correspondings id's of the input. Now I wish to pass through this array from top to bottom in a `while` loop. I am not using `foreach` because if it has children multiple elements should be processed together, and not come again in the next 'loop'.

```
function recursive_func($array){
    while ($i<=count($array)){
        if (isset($array[$i]['children'])){
             ?><div><?php
             recursive_function($array[$i]['children']);
             $i++;
             recursive_function($array[$i]['children']);
             $i++;
             ?></div><?php
             }
           else{
             ?><div>Something</div><?php
             $i++;
          }
     }
}
```

Clearly `$array[$i]['children']` aren't the children of the i'th element (by position), but of the key with value i.
How can I pass through this array in the order as in `$output`?

Comment: i dont understand why you can't use foreach() it would solve this easily

Comment: @Dagon I know. But if a row has children, it is a column, and the next row in order is the second column. These two should be wrapped in a <div>. A while loop allows me to run the two arrays inside the div, and then just 'jump over' the next row in the the loop

Comment: still doable esily via foreach

Comment: I am interested in the answer (I am working on a foreach myself). Please post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Garr Godfrey suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36119738/1557526), you can solve this with `array_keys()` like so

```
function recursive_func($array){
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    for ($i=0; $i<count($keys); $i++) {
        if (isset($array[ $keys[$i] ]['children'])) {
            recursive_func($array[ $keys[$i] ]['children']);
            $i++;
            recursive_func($array[ $keys[$i] ]['children']);
        } else {
            //sth, no $i++ here!
        }
    }
}
```

Because I am using a `for` loop here, the `$i++` inside the loop will make it possible for you to skip one element

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_keys to get the keys in sorted order, and iterate through those.
Or can also use array_values, then you can index sequentially. Just do it right at the start.

```
function recursivefunction( $array ) {
    $array = array_values($array);
    ....
}
```

I'm not sure why one entry having children means the next does as well, but I'll assume foreach is problematic.

Comment: From the inputted data i can be sure that one row with children, means the next one does too.
I can't use array_values because i'll lose the id's. However, array_keys might be useful, but will make it more complicated

Comment: Someone had downvoted your post when it only said array_values...
This method might just work.

Comment: it only said array_keys...which is exactly what you need.

Comment: array_keys was indeed what i needed

Answer (score 1):

Since the $output keys are not in order, one way is to do the following:

First get all the array keys:

```
$keys=array_keys($output);
```

Next, you may call the recursive_func($keys,$output):

```
function recursive_func($keys,$output){
    $size=count($keys);
    $i=0;
    while ($i<=$size){
        if (isset($output[$i]['children'])){
             ?><div><?php
             $a=$output[$i]['children'];
             recursive_function(array_keys($a),$a);
             $i++;
             $a=$output[$i]['children'];
             recursive_function(array_keys($a),$a);
             $i++;
             ?></div><?php
        }
        else{
             ?><div>Something</div><?php
             $i++;
        }
   }
}
```

Please note that it is better that you set the $size of the array outside of the loop for better performance

Comment: except the recursive calls don't pass the correct thing.

Comment: For the recursive call, you will need to pass the $keys array and the $output array

Comment: I think recursive_function($output[$keys[$i]]) passes the correct subarray

Comment: I am pretty sure this won't work. You are only putting array_keys in the recursive function, not the actually data

Comment: i am passing both the keys and the actual data     recursive_function(array_keys($a),$a);

Comment: I feel like kingkero's solution is the better one. I am wondering though, why is it  better to set $size outside the loop (source?)

Comment: @Pepe If you set `$size` outside the loop, it only gets calculated once. However, if you set in within the condition, it needs to be calculated at every iteration. You'll only feel the difference for large arrays though

Comment: Exactly what @Pepe stated. If you put $size outside the loop, it will only need to calculate the $size once instead of multiple times.

Comment: Same for a 'for' loop i guess?

Comment: Yes, same thing for the for() loop